# Prevent caching of web applications

Tags: reactjs, web, caching

Is there a way to disable caching of browsers when visiting websites?

I have a React web project that I access using i.e. Chrome. When I create a new version and load it up to the server, not all of the browsers update the site. For instance on my Android phone I have Chrome installed. When I visit a page, then update the site on the server to a new version, Chrome still displays the old previously loaded version. Even if I hit refresh, it still keeps the old page. I found [this article](https://wp-mix.com/disable-caching-html/) mentioning disabling caching. Is that the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get what you mean but try to put it inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the caching is the wrong approach. By using [cache busting](https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting) you can cache static assets for as long as necessary, but when they are updated, load the new versions.

How you implement it will depend on how you build for production and what stack you use. Some front end build tools such as Laravel Mix can do it for you, and things like Webpack can normally do it for you with a bit of configuration. Where that approach isn't viable I've also created helpers in languages like PHP and Javascript before to append the timestamp of the file as a query string parameter, which should also solve this issue.